# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

Given a binary tree and a sum, determine if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals the given sum.

Note: A leaf is a node with no children.

Example:

Given the below binary tree and sum = 22,

```
      5
     / \
    4   8
   /   / \
  11  13  4
 /  \      \
7    2      1
```

return true, as there exist a root-to-leaf path 5->4->11->2 which sum is 22.

```
class Solution(object):
def hasPathSum(self, root, sum):
    """
    :type root: TreeNode
    :type sum: int
    :rtype: bool
    """
    l = []
    def helper(tree, total):
        if not tree.left and not tree.right:
            l.append(total)
        else:
            helper(tree.left, total + tree.val)
            helper(tree.right, total + tree.val)
        return l

    if root:
        helper(root, 0)
        return sum in l
    return False
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code???

Comment: In a case where a node has only one son, let's say left, then `node.right is None`.  That will cause the second call to helper to throw the exception. Instead try to have another separate check for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that your helper improperly handles cases when a node's left or right child are `None`. It will recurse on both children and crash attempting to access `None.left` or `None.right`.

Beyond that, there is no need for a list here; you can return `True` if you reach a leaf and find that your running total equals the sum. This is more efficient because you avoid traversing the rest of the tree after finding a solution and avoid traversing the list to find your target after the tree search is over.

Also worth mentioning, Leetcode gives the parameter `sum`, which overwrites a builtin function. I usually rename such variables and took the liberty to do so here.

```
def hasPathSum(self, root, target):
    """
    :type root: TreeNode
    :type sum: int
    :rtype: bool
    """
    def helper(tree, total=0):
        if not tree.left and not tree.right:
            return target == total + tree.val

        if tree.left and helper(tree.left, total + tree.val):
            return True

        if tree.right and helper(tree.right, total + tree.val):
            return True

        return False


    return helper(root) if root else False
```